# Dataflow job fails due to inability to read ojdbc driver from the Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a working GCP account and trying to run a dataflow job which ingest data from on-prem oracle to BigQuery using cloud SDK. I have installed the versioned cloud SDK tool and configured my account. I want to use the JDBCToBigQuery template.
Tried executing:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.JdbcToBigQuery -Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false -Dexec.args="--driverJars=gs://********/jars/ojdbc8-8.0.17.jar --driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --connectionURL=***** --query='select * from schema.users' --outputTable= ***** --bigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory=***** --username=***** --password=****** --project=***** --runner=DirectRunner"
```

It throws this error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  08:24 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-21T23:02:45-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project google-cloud-teleport-java: An exception occured while executing the Java class. org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Error reading gs://********/jars/ojdbc8-8.0.17.jar: connect timed out -> [Help 1]
```

I am working behind the company's proxy but have taken care of that by incorporating proxy settings. 
Trying to troubleshoot this error, can anyone help out in this?
P.S.: Newbie to google cloud services

Comment: Can you reach the file from the command `gsutil ls gs://********/jars/ojdbc8-8.0.17.jar`? Did you try to perform the same thing from Cloud Shell? of course, the database connexion will failed, but this will validate your parameter and the jar download.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried gsutil ls gs://********/jars/ojdbc8-8.0.17.jar and can reach the file. From the cloud shell i tried running this: gcloud dataflow jobs run sample-run \--gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Jdbc_to_BigQuery \--parameters \driverJars=gs://********/jars/ojdbc8-8.0.17.jar,\driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver,\c
onnectionURL=*****,\query='select * from tdss_schema.cs_org_address_lh',\outputTable=*****,\bigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory=***** . The job gets created but it eventually fails. How can I run it using cloud SDK?

Comment: To run dataflow from gcloud:
The same above command should work for you from gcloud as well. 
gcloud dataflow jobs run dataflowjobname --gcs-location=templatelocation
 --paramter.......
And in you compile command you need to specify runner=DataflowRunner

Comment: @truptijadhav. Eventually, I think it's a firewall/proxy issue. I don't have the same network configuration as you and it's hard for me to test and to provide the right answer. I can only propose  you another solution: Extract the Oracle data into files (for example in CSV), upload the file to Cloud Storage, change only the BeamIO for getting file from Storage, and it should work. If your extract are exactly in the same format as your query in the Beam code, you only have to change the source into Beam. It's the power of this framework!

Comment: Thanks Arun, I did specify that. @guillaum eblaquiere I am able to move the data when it's in csv format. But it does not work JdbcToBigQuery template and i want that to get working. Thank you anyways. I would appreciate if you guys come up with any other solution. I will give it a shot.

Comment: Can you verify that your local firewall enables access to the GCS endpoint.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints

Please try to ping storage.googleapis.com on the command line and see if it replies.

You may also need to open up endpoints to other GCP services which you are accessing. This include the Dataflow service: dataflow.googleapis.com. And the services for other GCP source/sink you are using

Comment: One test you can try is to create a new ubuntu VM in Google Compute Engine using this GitHub repository [1], specifying (name, zone and service account with permissions). Once done, connect to it through remote desktop [2] and try to run the Dataflow job from there, if you finally suceed we can guess that is an issue in the machine you are using and the connection to Google Cloud.


[1] https://github.com/Oscar-Rod/desktopVM
[2] https://remotedesktop.google.com